# Is it possible to update UI information dynamically?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

Apologies if my title doesn't really catch the essence of what I'm trying to ask/accomplish but hopefully my description will.

To keep it basic for this example, I have numerous text instances on screen, these needs to be updated at least once a second with new information. I was currently creating the UI using the following code:

```
function BuildItemList() {
var iButtonCount = 0;

for (var i in CORE.Items) {
    if (CORE.Items[i].Display) {
        var ItemStyle = ItemCanAffordStyle;

        if (!CanAfford(YAROS.Items[i].Name))
            ItemStyle = ItemCannotAffordStyle;

        var ItemButton = sys.add.button((800 - 205), (25 + (65 * iButtonCount)), 'ItemButton', this.BuyItem.bind(this, CORE.Items[i].Name), this);

        if (HasPrerequisites(CORE.Items[i].Name))
            sys.add.text(ItemButton.x + 10, ItemButton.y + 10, CORE.Items[i].DisplayName, ItemStyle);
        else
            sys.add.text(ItemButton.x + 10, ItemButton.y + 10, '???', ItemStyle);

        if (CORE.Items[i].Versioned)
            sys.add.text((ItemButton.x + ItemButton.width) - 30, ItemButton.y + 10, 'v' + YAROS.Items[i].UserOwns, ItemStyle);
        else
            sys.add.text((ItemButton.x + ItemButton.width) - 30, ItemButton.y + 10, YAROS.Items[i].UserOwns, ItemStyle);

        var iCostsCount = 0;
        var sResourceCosts = CORE.Items[i].BuyResources.split(',');
        var sResourceCostsAmount = CORE.Items[i].BuyUnits.toString().split(',');

        for (var x = 0; x < sResourceCosts.length; x++) {
            var ItemDetailsStyle = ItemDetailsCanAffordStyle;

            if (sResourceCostsAmount[x] > CORE.Resources[sResourceCosts[x]].CurrentCount)
                ItemDetailsStyle = ItemDetailsCannotAffordStyle;

            sys.add.image(ItemButton.x + (10 + (60 * iCostsCount)), ItemButton.y + 35, CORE.Resources[sResourceCosts[x]].ImageName);
            sys.add.text(ItemButton.x + (30 + (60 * iCostsCount)), ItemButton.y + 37, parseFloat(parseFloat(sResourceCostsAmount[x]).toFixed(CORE.Resources[sResourceCosts[x]].DecimalPlaces)), ItemDetailsStyle);
            iCostsCount++;
        }

        iButtonCount++;
        }
    }
}
```

The above code did work, however I quickly realised that this creates all of the elements over each other when all I want to do is update the information I've already created.

So finally my question, do I need to create each element, assign that element to a variable, and then have a separate "Update" function to assign new values to the variables?

I don't need help re-writing it to do this, however am I thinking correctly? Or is there another/proper way to do this?

Thank you.

Comment: Have you seen the Phaser example on [how to update text?](http://phaser.io/examples/v2/text/update-text)

Comment: @MikeC I have yeah, that was my thinking for how I may have to do it, however as I have 3 items of text within each button and 9 buttons, I was thinking that there would be some way of looping through each text element instead of hard coding each label to a variable it has to loop.

Comment: Sure. Put them in an [array](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) then loop through the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After going away from the code and coming back (after reading Mike C's comment), I've been going about this the hard way.

I'm going to assign all of the needed button elements to an array, in the order that they appear on screen, I will then loop through the array and update the information.

This seems like the most sensible way to accomplish this.